# Find javascript snippet from Google Result page

Tags: javascript, api, google-search

I understand that you can find javascript from the source code of the page. However, none of the lines are formatted. If I'm looking for a javascript snippet from a Google results page, how would I get it?

Example,

I want to figure out how Google displays the address of a business i typed in Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Google Chrome browser, launch F12 Developer Tools (by either click F12 or right-clicking within the page and selecting INSPECT ELEMENT) while on the page you are trying to analyze.

Then navigate to the SOURCES tab. Here, you will find a hierarchical of all scripts and their respective parent domains/paths that are being utilized by the page you are on.

Comment: You can just as easily do this with any other modern browser, however I would suggest Chrome F12 Developer Tools for ease of use.

Comment: I'm trying Firebug for Firefox

Comment: Absolutely the same principle. Viewing source will deliver full fledged markup and, in the event that scripts are external resources, will not show them.

Using DevTools or FireBug will show you a cleaner, separated version of the script source.

Comment: Does Google encrypt their javascript?  Looks like it. There is stuff I don't recognize.

Comment: It's entirely possible that it's minified, obfuscated and scrambled. That would be consistent with best practices for release from a behemoth like Google that doesn't want people snooping, copying or even understanding how their product works.